# How to apply css under iframe in SPFx webpart?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have a SPFx web-part that has a iframe section (to display SharePoint document library out of box view). How can I apply the same CSS format from the main page to the page displayed in the iframe?